# Text box not appearing in a Messages conversation

Tags: messages

I have a recurring problem in Messages on my Mac where, in one group conversation in particular, the text box occasionally disappears. Instead of having a text box at the bottom of the screen I can type into, the conversation simply goes all the way down. When this happens, the text box still appears in every other conversation; I can also still send messages in that conversation from my iPhone. It disappears only on my Mac, and only on that one conversation. The problem persists when I shut down Messages and start it back up. Sometimes the text box comes back, and then later disappears again, on a pattern that I have not been able to discern.

Any thoughts?

Messages 8.0
Mac OS 10.10.2

Comment: Same problem. Any answers?

Answer (score 5):

From [another site](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29083577#29083577), try disabling and then re-enabling the account in question as follows.

Within the Messages app:

- Select the conversation that has the problem (I don't know that this is necessary, but I did it anyway)
- Go to Messages->Preferences...->Accounts
- In the box at the left hand side, select the account in question -- it will probably be your Apple ID with "iMessage" below it
- Then over on the right, make sure "Settings" (and not "Blocked") is selected near the top
- Still on the right, underneath your Apple ID, uncheck "Enable this account"
- **At that point, back in the main Messages app you should see the text box reappear at the bottom of the conversation**
- Then re-check "Enable this account"

Done.

P.S. This was done on *OS X El Capitan* (Version 10.11.1), and *Messages* app version 9.0 (5084)

Comment: This only helps short term. Every time I do this, a short while later, the input field is gone again.